# How to set a specific destination directory when install a package using installpkg tool of slackware

Tags: slackware

I am trying to make a package and install it in slackware OS.
My package only has a binary executable file.
I have created the package with .tgz file using makepkg tool.
But when I tried to install the package using the installpkg tool the binary file always extracted to the root directory. 
So how can I change the destination directory to some other location (like /usr/bin).

What is the use of doinst.sh script in the package.Can I write my own script in it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Make temporary directory
2. Make tree structure of installed files
3. Make install/ directory with 'slack-desc' file and (optional) 'doinst.sh'
4. Run makepkg /tmp/package-name-version-arch-build_tag.txz

   ```
   # mkdir /tmp/pkg; cd /tmp/pkg
   # mkdir -p usr/bin
   # cp /path/to/your/file usr/bin/
   # chmod a+x usr/bin/file
   # mkdir install
   # cat <<EOF >install/slack-desc
   appname: appname (short description of app)
   appname:
   appname: Long description of appname, wrapped at 71 characters *after* the
   appname: colon following "appname" (and the 'handy ruler' should start at
   appname: that colon and be exactly 71 characters long).
   appname: If there is room, there might be a link to the homepage of the
   appname: application on one of these lines, but it's not necessary.
   appname:
   appname: The maximum number of lines prefixed by "appname:" is 11.
   appname: Lines without any other text should *not* have a space after the :
   appname:
   EOF
   # makepkg /tmp/appname-1.0-x86_64-1_me.txz
   # upgradepkg --install-new /tmp/appname-1.0-x86_64-1_me.txz
   ```

Comment: Remember that Slackware setup uses ash to install OS, so don't use incompatible commands in your doinst.sh script.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Is it possible to extract the binary file to a particular directory when we type installpkg command Now in the above example shown it is copying the binary file to usr/bin manually before we are running makepkg command . My intention is to create a directory and put the binary file in it and make a package of .tgz.Then when install it using installpkg I need that binary to be extracted to the /usr/bin of my system.

Comment: Please note binary file goes to /tmp/pkg/usr/bin/file. When you run makepkg in /tmp/pkg directory, the package gets complete subtree from current directory (/tmp/pkg), so package contains usr/bin/file. When you run installpkg the file goes to /usr/bin/file.